# How do I call this list from another class in C#?

Tags: arrays, list, csv

I am still new to the whole C# thing but I found this code posted from grovesNL about 5 years ago which I believe will work.

```
 namespace DataAccessClass
{
    public class FileReader
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DailyValues> values = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Sample.csv")
                                           .Skip(1)
                                           .Select(v => DailyValues.FromCsv(v))
                                           .ToList();
        }
    }

    public class DailyValues
    {
        DateTime Date;
        decimal Open;
        decimal High;
        decimal Low;
        decimal Close;
        decimal Volume;
        decimal AdjClose;

        public static DailyValues FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');
            DailyValues dailyValues = new DailyValues();
            dailyValues.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0]);
            dailyValues.Open = Convert.ToDecimal(values[1]);
            dailyValues.High = Convert.ToDecimal(values[2]);
            dailyValues.Low = Convert.ToDecimal(values[3]);
            dailyValues.Close = Convert.ToDecimal(values[4]);
            dailyValues.Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(values[5]);
            dailyValues.AdjClose = Convert.ToDecimal(values[6]);
            return dailyValues;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to read a csv file skipping the header and get it into a list that is accessible from another class.  So my Architecture is DataAccessClass that has a class called FileReader and a class called Values. My task is to read this csv file into class FileReader and then to create an object list to hold it in the class Values.  When I go to the Values class to call it I can't figure it out. This is how I am trying to call it. It is saying DailyValues.FromCsv(string) is a method that is not valid.

```
    public List<string> GetList()
        {
            return DataAccessClass.DailyValues.FromCsv.dailyValues;


        }
```

I want to be able to access this list further up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression `DataAccessClass.DailyValues.FromCsv.dailyValues` is the culprit.

`DataAccessClass.DailyValues.FromCsv` is valid, and references the static method named `FromCsv` in the class `DataAccessClass.DailyValues`. But then going on by adding `.dailyValues` is incorrect. It is a method, nothing to peek into and extract stuff using `.`.

You could (if that was the intention) call the function, and directly work with the result:

`DataAccessClass.DailyValues.FromCsv(some_csv_string)` is an expression of type `DailyValues`. There you could then access - as an example - 'High' with:

```
DailyValues dv;
dv = DataAccessClass.DailyValues.FromCsv(some_csv_string);
dosomething(dv.High);
```

But for that to work, `High` would have to have the visibility of `public`.